# Adding a row and appending values to columns in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, append

I am trying to append `10 , 5, 890, 50, Finish` for the `Date,High,Low,Volume,Symbol` at the end of the `input.csv` file. It will format the contents of the csv file permanently so I use `data.to_csv(url,index=False)`. How would I be able to do that?

```
import pandas as pd
url= 'input.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(url, low_memory=False)
data.to_csv(url,index=False)
```

Current output:

```
Date,High,Low,Volume,Symbol
2021-01-15 00:04:00,39358.98,39273.24,0.4786072902,BTCUSD
2021-01-15 00:03:00,39362.37,39166.19,0.2911817448,BTCUSD
2021-01-15 00:02:00,39187.06,39017.72,6.2488076695,BTCUSD
```

Expected output:

```
Date,High,Low,Volume,Symbol
2021-01-15 00:04:00,39358.98,39273.24,0.4786072902,BTCUSD
2021-01-15 00:03:00,39362.37,39166.19,0.2911817448,BTCUSD
2021-01-15 00:02:00,39187.06,39017.72,6.2488076695,BTCUSD
10 , 5, 890, 50, Finish
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `loc`:

```
data = pd.read_csv(url, low_memory=False)

data.loc[len(data)] = [10 , 5, 890, 50, 'Finish' ]
data.to_csv(url,index=False)
```

Comment: what is df supposed to be?

Comment: Oh, that's `data`. Usually we use `df` for dataframe.

Comment: oh I see thanks for the clarification is the purpose of the .loc function to read the rows?

Comment: @egeSelcuk ít can be used both to get and to set the values.